# PrestaShop - Login programmatically

Tags: mobile, authentication, passwords, prestashop

I am writing a android and windows native app. The native app stores the login details as reated for mulitple other web apps, and logs them into this when browsing to them from the native app.

one of the buttons in my app open a prestashop site for a authenticated user. How can i set the username and password and log that user in to the site programmitcally, giving the illusion and user experience that he has been seemlessly authenticated and accessed to his shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically do the same as the PrestaShop login form does, which is (for v1.5 at least):

Sending a POST request to **http(s)://yourshop.com/index.php?controller=authentication** with the following parameters:

- **email**: your customer's email address
- **passwd**: your customer's password
- **back**: name of the controller you want to be redirected to after success (ex: my-account)
- **SubmitLogin**: put anything there, it just needs to be true, so that the controller knows it's a login action

If it doesn't work, your version may work differently and you will have to check the network tab of your favourite developer tool, to see what kind of request is sent with which parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but theres another way which i find better for the purpose.

You include the `AuthController` from the controllers folder, set your post-parameters and execute the `postProcess()` method. After this, you can check the "`$authController->errors`" array for errors. If it's empty - the login was successful.

Example:

```
public function hookDisplayHeader()
{
    if ($this->context->cookie->isLogged())
    {
        return;
    } else {
        $acceptLogin = false;

        if( isset( $_POST["email"] ) && isset( $_POST["passwd"] ) )
        {
            $acceptLogin = $this->attemptLogin($_POST["email"],$_POST["passwd"]);
        }

        if( $acceptLogin )
            return;
        die( $this->display(__FILE__, 'logintemplate.tpl') );
    }
}
protected function attemptLogin($email, $password)
{
    include _PS_FRONT_CONTROLLER_DIR_ . "AuthController.php";
    $auth = new AuthController();
    $auth->isAjax = true;
    $_POST["email"] = $email;
    $_POST["passwd"] = $password;
    $_POST["SubmitLogin"] = true;
    $auth->postProcess();
    if( count($auth->errors) > 0 )
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign( "errors", $auth->errors );
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Edit: This no longer works with Prestashop 1.6. As of PS 1.6 `$auth->postProcess()` either redirects or sends the ajaxs response immediately. There is no way to circumvent this. If you want to do something after login, you have to make two ajax calls.