# programmatical login in prestashop

Tags: php, ajax, post, prestashop

I have inside a cookie an encrypted link containing the email and password of a cutomer.
When i go to this page, the email and password are decripted (all this works fine).

I found a thread that tells me to pass 3 parameters in POST method to a certain url:
email, passwd, submitLogin.
referenced thread -> [PrestaShop - Login programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401341/prestashop-login-programmatically)

I have no other choise then to do this login using ajax post method like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>

<?php

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}

$email = base64_url_decode($_GET['id']);
$password = base64_url_decode($_GET['pwd']);

?>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.post('index.php?controller=authentication', { back: 'my-account', email: '<?php echo $email ?>', passwd : '<?php echo $password ?>', SubmitLogin: 1},
            function(returnedData){
                console.log(returnedData);
            }).fail(function(){
            console.log("error");
        });
    });
</script>
```

However the response of the ajax corresponds to the login page without any message in particular.

Would anyone have any idea why it doesn't log us in?

Comment: have you checked the values sent in the post for the email and passwd?

Comment: i just now found the issue. i will make and accept my awnser in a bit. 
i thank you for your time and interest though. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue.

the previous thread i got the awnser from is correct but solely for their version of prestashop (v1.5) all the while i work with v1.7 (current latest).

the difference is the nameage of the post variables the controller verifies:
v1.5:

- email
- passwd
- SubmitLogin

while in v1.7 these should be changed to:

- email
- password
- submitLogin

So changing the name of the post values did it for me.
I still have the issue of it returning a fail on my ajax post but it works fine oddly enough.

I thank everyone who took the time to read my post.